# Mean, median and mode GUI

Tags: python, calculator, statistics, tkinter

This program takes x numbers and displays the mean, median and mode.

My goal here was to use classes and class properties the best i could to make the code shorter (honestly i may have just made it longer), so i would like to get some feedback on that.

````
import tkinter as tk
from typing import Callable, List
from statistics import mean, median, mode

"""MainFunctions = initialization creates 2 starting input boxes and the 3 outputs"""
"""Input = initialization creates an entry and stringvar for input"""
"""Output = initialization creates a label for the name of the average and another for the output"""


class Input:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk, index: int, callback: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
        self.value_var = tk.StringVar(parent)
        self.value_var.trace_add(mode="write", callback=callback)

        self.value_entry = tk.Entry(
            parent, textvariable=self.value_var
        )
        self.value_entry.grid(row=index, column=1)

    def delete_entry(self) -> None:
        self.value_entry.destroy()

    @property
    def value(self) -> str:
        if self.value_var.get():
            return self.value_var.get()
        else:
            return None

    @property
    def row(self) -> int:
        grid_info = self.value_entry.grid_info()
        return grid_info['row']


class Output:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk, index: int, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

        self.name_label = tk.Label(parent, text=f"{name}:")
        self.name_label.grid(row=index, column=0)

        self.output_label = tk.Label(parent, text=0)
        self.output_label.grid(row=index, column=1)

    def grid(self, row) -> None:
        self.name_label.grid(row=row, column=0)
        self.output_label.grid(row=row, column=1)

    def set_output(self, values) -> None:
        try:
            match self.name:
                case "Mean": self.output_label.configure(text=mean(values))
                case "Median": self.output_label.configure(text=median(values))
                case "Mode": self.output_label.configure(text=mode(values))
        except:
            self.output_label.configure(text=0)


class MainFunctions:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk) -> None:
        self.parent = parent

        self.inputs = [
            Input(self.parent, 0, self.input_callback),
            Input(self.parent, 1, self.input_callback)
        ]

        self.outputs = [
            Output(
                self.parent, 2, "Mean"
            ),
            Output(
                self.parent, 3, "Median"
            ),
            Output(
                self.parent, 4, "Mode"
            )
        ]

    def create_destroy_input(self) -> None:
        """Counts the number of empty stringvars"""
        empty_stringvars = 0

        for input in self.inputs[::-1]:
            if input.value == None:
                empty_stringvars += 1

        """Deletes all empty entries and stringvars except for 1, then creates another"""
        for input in self.inputs[::-1]:
            if empty_stringvars <= 1:
                self.inputs += [
                    Input(
                        self.parent, len(self.inputs), self.input_callback
                    )
                ]
                return
            if input.value == None:
                input.delete_entry()
                self.inputs.remove(input)
                empty_stringvars -= 1

    def grid_output(self) -> None:
        """To grid the output according to the how many entries there are"""
        row = 1

        for output in self.outputs:
            output.grid(row + len(self.inputs))
            row += 1

    def get_values(self) -> List:
        """Gets all values in entries"""
        values = []

        for input in self.inputs:
            try:
                value = input.value.replace(",", ".")
                values.append(float(value))
            except:
                pass

        return values

    def set_output(self, values) -> None:
        """Calls function for setting output 3 times for each output label"""
        for output in self.outputs:
            output.set_output(values)

    def input_callback(self, name: str, mode: str, index: str) -> None:
        """Every stringvar calls back to this"""
        self.create_destroy_input()
        self.grid_output()
        self.set_output(self.get_values())


def main() -> None:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Mean, median and mode calculator")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    MainFunctions(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

```
````